# How can reduce frame rate in .PNG to MP4 converter in cv2 by python?

Tags: python, mp4, frame-rate, opencv

I have tried many times unsuccessfully to change the framerate to make video slower like `out = cv2.VideoWriter(fps=2.5)` but generally, it doesn't perform slower why? Any idea to fix this problem? Also, I would appreciate that if anyone has a solution to convert directly pictures to `gif`

```py
import cv2
import argparse
import os

# Construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-ext", "--extension", required=False, default='png', help="extension name. default is 'png'.")
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", required=False, default='output.mp4', help="output video file")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# Arguments
dir_path = '.'
ext = args['extension']
output = args['output']

images = []
for f in os.listdir(dir_path):
    if f.endswith(ext):
        images.append(f)

# Determine the width and height from the first image
image_path = os.path.join(dir_path, images[0])
frame = cv2.imread(image_path)
cv2.imshow('video',frame)
height, width, channels = frame.shape

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v') # Be sure to use lower case
out = cv2.VideoWriter(output, fourcc, 1.5, (width, height))

for image in images:

    image_path = os.path.join(dir_path, image)
    frame = cv2.imread(image_path)

    out.write(frame) # Write out frame to video

    cv2.imshow('video',frame)
    if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF) == ord('q'): # Hit `q` to exit
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

print("The output video is {}".format(output))
```

Comment: The title says you want to convert PNGs to MP4. The question asks if anyone knows how to convert some pictures of unknown type to GIF. Could you be clearer about what you want to do please?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to convert images to a gif file:

```
import os
import imageio

dir_path = 'path/to/gifFolder/'
img_folder_path = 'path/to/imagefolder/'

images = []
for f in os.listdir(img_folder_path):
    if f.endswith('jpg'):
        images.append(f)

videowriter = imageio.get_writer(dir_path+'movie.gif', fps=5) 
for filename in images[0:30]:
    print(filename)
    img = imageio.imread(img_folder_path+filename)
    videowriter.append_data(img)

videowriter.close()
```